# Issue Detecting Button cellForRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to detect if the button has been clicked in the UITableViewController

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

 let LikesBtn = cell.viewWithTag(7) as! UIButton

}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55975789/1271826. And, FWIW, I’d suggest avoiding cryptic tag numbers. Hook up your buttons to meaningful `@IBOutlet` and `@IBAction` names.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest and most efficient way in Swift is a callback closure.

- Subclass `UITableViewCell`, the *viewWithTag* way to identify UI elements is outdated.
- Set the class of the custom cell to the name of the subclass and set the identifier to `ButtonCellIdentifier` in Interface Builder.
- Add a `callback` property.
- Add an action and connect the button to the action.

  ```
  class ButtonCell: UITableViewCell {

      var callback : (() -> Void)?

      @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender : UIButton) {
         callback?()
      }
  }
  ```
- In `cellForRow` assign the callback to the custom cell.

  ```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ButtonCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! ButtonCell
       cell.callback = {
           print("Button pressed", indexPath)  
       }
       return cell
    }
  ```
- When the button is pressed the callback is called. The index path is captured.

**Edit**

There is a caveat if cells can be added or removed. In this case pass the `UITableViewCell` instance as parameter and get the index path from there

```
class ButtonCell: UITableViewCell {

    var callback : ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender : UIButton) {
       callback?(self)
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ButtonCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! ButtonCell
     let item = dataSourceArray[indexPath.row]
     // do something with item
     cell.callback = { cell in
         let actualIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)!
         print("Button pressed", actualIndexPath)  
     }
     return cell
  }
```

If even the `section` can change, well, then protocol/delegate may be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

First step:
Make Subclass for your custom UITableViewCell, also register protocol.

Something like this:

```
protocol MyTableViewCellDelegate: class {
    func onButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton, indexPath: IndexPath)
}

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var cellButton: UIButton!

    var cellIndexPath: IndexPath!
    weak var delegate: MyTableViewCellDelegate!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        cellButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    func onButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate.onButtonPressed(sender, indexPath: cellIndexPath)
    }

}
```

In your TableViewController, make sure it conform to your just created protocol "MyTableViewCellDelegate".

Look at the code below for better understanding.

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, MyTableViewCellDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as? MyTableViewCell {

            cell.cellIndexPath = indexPath
            cell.delegate = self

            return cell
        } else {
            print("Something wrong. Check your cell idetifier or cell subclass")
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }

    func onButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton, indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("DID PRESSED BUTTON WITH TAG = \(sender.tag) AT INDEX PATH = \(indexPath)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure to make the `delegate` a `weak` property. I’d also advise against storing the `indexPath` in the cell, because it will be invalid as soon as another row is inserted or deleted earlier in the table. A more minor point, but I might suggest moving the `MyTableViewCellDelegate` into an extension to keep the code a little better organized.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I use:

First initialize the button as an `Outlet` and its `action` on your `TableViewCell`

```
class MainViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var testButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func testBClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let tag = sender.tag //with this you can get which button was clicked 

}



}
```

Then in you Main Controller in the cellForRow function just initialize the tag of the button like this:

```
class MainController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, {

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! MainViewCell


        cell.testButton.tag = indexPath.row        

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Couldn’t agree more, i also use it in my projects and works like a charm

Comment: Do not use the index path as the tag if the table view supports the ability to delete, insert, or move rows.

Comment: @rmaddy if the table view can insert delete or move rows then it will reload itself so the tag will be initialize again and buttons will have the correct index don't they ? (I haven't check it but I believe it won't have problem)

Comment: Only if you needlessly call reloadData which you should not do just to remove, insert, or reload a row.