# Add target for button in table view cells

Tags: swift, uitableview, addtarget

I have a table view that its cells have a button in themselves and these buttons should open a view with an unique id. So I need to passing an argument to my buttons but with `addTarget` property I just can call function without any parameter.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
...
    cell.editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToEdit(id:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

func goToEdit(id: String) {
    let edit = EditAdViewController(editingAdId: id)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(edit, animated: true)
}
```

Is there any way to refer an action with some parameters to a button? Thanks everyone :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46379494/3746301

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to link your button to a @IBAction and use params[indexPath.row].

To get the indexPath:

```
var cell = sender.superview() as? UITableViewCell 
var indexPath: IndexPath? = yourTableView.indexPath(for: cell!)
```

Comment: unfortunately #selector can't get any parameter

Comment: try to link you button to a @IBAction and use params[indexPath.row].
to get the indexPath:
var cell = sender.superview() as? UITableViewCell
var indexPath: IndexPath? = yourTableView.indexPath(for: cell!)

Comment: @LucasMoraes Don't post code in comments. [Edit] your answer will all relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding delegate functions to your custom UITableViewCell.

For example, I have a button inside this custom tableViewCell:

**PickupTableViewCell.swift**

```
    import UIKit

protocol PickupTableViewCellDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func pickupTableViewCell(userDidTapPickup pickup: Pickup, pickupTableViewCell: PickupTableViewCell)
}

class PickupTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    // MARK: - Properties

    @IBOutlet private weak var label_UserFullName: UILabel!
    ....

    // MARK: - Functions
    // MARK: IBAction

    @IBAction func pickup(_ sender: Any) {
        self.delegate?.pickupTableViewCell(userDidTapPickup: self.pickup, pickupTableViewCell: self)
    }
}
```

Then in I conform my controller via the  `UITableViewDataSource (cellForRow)` and of course implement the delegate function of my tableViewCell.

**HomeViewController.swift**

```
// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let pickupTVC = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: R.reuseIdentifier.pickupTableViewCell)!
        pickupTVC.delegate = self
        pickupTVC.pickup = self.pickups[indexPath.section]

        return pickupTVC
    }
}

// MARK: - PickupTableViewCellDelegate

extension HomeViewController: PickupTableViewCellDelegate {
    func pickupTableViewCell(userDidTapPickup pickup: Pickup, pickupTableViewCell: PickupTableViewCell) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```