# How to transfer data from TableviewCell to SecondTableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I transfer data from one tableviewCell to another tableviewCell?

My app is a calculator and every time I click the minus or plus button it adds the numbers to my labels.

My proplem is that I cant add a segue inside my TableViewCell and I need to transfer the data that I added with buttons to my SecondTableViewCell.

Both tableViewCells are using the same code below:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var totalPar1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var plusminusPar1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var currentPar1: UILabel!

var totalPAR1: Int = 0
var plusminusPAR1: Int = 0
var currentPAR1: Int = 3
var total2PAR1: Int = 3

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    refreshLabels1()
    refreshLabels()
}
@IBAction func minusbutton1(_ sender: Any) {
addToAll(valueToAdd: -1)
    refreshLabels()
}
private func addToAll(valueToAdd: Int) {
    totalPAR1 += valueToAdd
    plusminusPAR1 += valueToAdd
    currentPAR1 += valueToAdd
}
private func refreshLabels() {
    self.currentPar1.text = String(currentPAR1)
}

@IBAction func plusButton1(_ sender: Any) {
addToAll1(valueToAdd: +1)
    refreshLabels1()
}
private func addToAll1(valueToAdd: Int) {
    totalPAR1 += valueToAdd
    plusminusPAR1 += valueToAdd
    currentPAR1 += valueToAdd
}
private func refreshLabels1() {
    self.totalPar1.text = String(totalPAR1)
    self.currentPar1.text = String(currentPAR1)
}
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

}
```

Comment: Don't repost questions.

Comment: @vadian How is this duplicated? I asked on that other how to transfer it to other view controller and I got answer for it. And now I'm asking how to transfer it to other cell controller WITHOUT SEGUE because you can't use segues there. If you cant read whole text you shouldn't post something like this..

Comment: OK I reopened the question but there was another (probably deleted) question where I wrote a comment that your approach is basically wrong because you are misusing the view. The **view** is only for displaying data. The math and the workflow is supposed to belong to the **controller**.

Comment: @vadian If I move that calculator to my view controller, how I can get my labels and buttons from my TableviewCell to my view controller also?

Comment: You need a data model which the labels are updated from in `cellForRow` and a callback or protocol/delegate to handle the button clicks in the controller to do the math, update the model and reload the view. That makes it very easy to pass the data to another controller because you have to move only the model instance.

Comment: @vadian is it possible that you tell what kind method I can use on my protocol to save button click can't find it..

Comment: Here is a simple example how to use a callback: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378515/issue-detecting-button-cellforrowat/46379494#46379494

Comment: @vadian So just under: "cell.callback = {" I make my valueadd?

Comment: Yes, the example is very simple, of course you can also pass parameters.

Comment: @vadian Okay thanks a lot ill try it later