# Performing a segue with the TableViewCell IndexPath value

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIButton within a TableViewCell and I would like to perform a segue when the UIButton is tapped, but I need to know the IndexPath.row value in the moment of perform the segue. Here more details:

[image]

Code block where I perform the segue:

```
}else if(segue.identifier == "toChat"){
            let chatController = segue.destination as! ChatViewController
            chatController.employeeSender = self.employeeData
            //Currently I have tried this, but indexPath comes nil
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            chatController.employeeReceiver = (self.searchController!.isActive) ? self.searchResults[indexPath.row] : self.employeeArray[indexPath.row]
                print("Receiver Data\(self.employeeArray[indexPath.row].alias)")
            }

        }
```

Thank you,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41887007/5461400

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378515/issue-detecting-button-cellforrowat/46379494#46379494. A callback closure is a very easy and efficient solution.

Comment: @vadian, this works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1) Easy

You can add tag to your button in the `cellForRowAtindexPath` and when you got tapped event of button you can create `indexPath` with that.

2) Create Subclass you `UIButton` and have one `IndexPath`  property in it. and assign indexpath in cellForRow now you can access `button.indexPath` when button is tapped

Don't forgot to pass event to your viewcontroller with delegate or clouser

Hope it is helpful

Comment: You have more than two options .

Comment: @vadian Sir Ifor right now i have only two options in mind :D Please feel free to update answer I trust you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! yourcustomcell
        cell.yourbutton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.yourbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.chatbutton), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
 }

// Button Click
 @objc func chatbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toChat", sender: sender.tag)
 }


 // MARK: - prepare segue

   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "toChat" {
                let chatController = segue.destination as! ChatViewController
                chatController.employeeSender = self.employeeData
                if let row = sender as? Int  {
                    chatController.employeeReceiver = (self.searchController!.isActive) ? self.searchResults[row] : self.employeeArray[row]
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also get the value of the cell's indexPath from which the button is tapped using the following extension.

```
public extension UITableView {

    func indexPathForView(_ view: UIView) -> IndexPath? {
        let center = view.center
        let viewCenter = self.convert(center, from: view.superview)
        let indexPath = self.indexPathForRow(at: viewCenter)
        return indexPath
    }
}
```

and get the indexPath in your @IBAction method of the button

```
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForView(sender)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! yourcustomcell
        cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
 }

// Button Click
 @objc func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        pushToChatController(self.employeeReceiverArray[sender.tag])
 }


 func pushToChatController(aEmployeeReceiver: EmployeeReceiver) {
        let chatController: ChatViewController = UIStoryboard.chatStoryboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: kChatViewControllerStoryboardId) as! ChatViewController
        chatController. employeeReceiver = aEmployeeReceiver
        navigationController?.pushViewController(chatController, animated: true)
  }
```

//NOTE:
    class func chatStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard {
        return UIStoryboard(name: “Chat”, bundle: nil)
    }

Let kChatViewControllerStoryboardId = “kChatViewControllerStoryboardId”
//Storyboard Identifier