# Can I attach parameters (not sender) to uiButton.addTarget in Swift 4

Tags: swift, uibutton

I'm new to iOS development. Please check below code.

```
let dropDown = DropDown()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dropDown.anchorView = dropDownTest // UIView or UIBarButtonItem
    dropDown.dataSource = ["Car", "Motorcycle", "Truck"]
    dropDown.bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y:(dropDown.anchorView?.plainView.bounds.height)!)
    dropDownTest.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc private func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    dropDown.show()
}
```

That was pretty easy because the variable `dropDown` can be called from `buttonClicked` method. But, in my case, i have to do this inside a table-cell-related method `cellForRowAt`.

```
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VarientCell", for: indexPath)

        let varientButtonTag = 1

        let varientButton = cell.viewWithTag(varientButtonTag) as! UIButton
        let varientDropDown = DropDown()
        varientDropDown.anchorView = varientButton
        varientDropDown.dataSource = datasource
        varientDropDown.bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: varientButton.bounds.height)

        varientButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.varientButtonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
```

and button clicked method,

```
    @objc private func varientButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
       //dropDown.show() 
       // my problem is here.., i need to pass the dropDown somehow to show that. 
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just access dropDown in the selector method as it is?

Comment: ok you can't ....

Comment: i need something like button.setOnClickListener( { } ); as in Android.

Comment: You can't pass custom parameters in an action but you can create a custom cell and use a callback closure rather than target/action

Comment: why you want to keep reference to drop views isn't it the dataSource that meant to differentiate between items

Comment: @vadian, how? can u give an example link for callback?

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378515/issue-detecting-button-cellforrowat/46379494#46379494

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. I'm pointing two possible ways. 
1. You can subclass UIButton and have the parameters to it.

```
class MyButton: UIButton{

       var myParam1: String?
       var myParam2: String?

    }
```

2. Create custom tableview cell and handle the button call inside

   import UIKit

   ```
   class MyCell: UITableViewCell{
       @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
       @IBOutlet weak var anotherButton: UIButton!
       func setup(model: YourDataModel){

           myButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.didSelect(_ :), for: .touchUpInside)
           anotherButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.didSelect(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
       }

       @objc func didSelect(_ sender: UIButton){
           switch sender {
           case myButton:
               print("my button clicked")
           case anotherButton:
               print("anotherButton clicked")
           default:
               break
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I think Subclass might be suitable. I was thinking to do that. Just finding better solution.