# Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewWrapperView' to 'UITableView' below iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom UITableCell for UITableView which has a button on it.

I use the following code to detect the indexPath of the cell using this code and pass the index so that I can take appropriate actions on the View Controller for the cell.

This works fine on iOS 11 and above but doesn't work below it. Please help me understand why this happens and how can I avoid this error. I am so stuck with this. Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

```
class PostCellView: UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate:  PostCellViewDelegate?

    // utilities
    @IBAction func cellAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let tableView : UITableView = self.superview as! UITableView
        let indexPath: IndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: self.center)!

        delegate?.cellTaskerAction(row : indexPath.row)
    }
}
```

I can't use a callback closure in the custom cell which is set in cellForRow and is called in an IBAction of the custom cell (as suggested by @vadian at [Issue Detecting Button cellForRowAt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378515/issue-detecting-button-cellforrowat/46379494#46379494)). I have cells being deleted and because cellForRow isn't refreshed every time, some cells still have the last index saved which results in bugs. Please help me find a solution to this.

Comment: The error is pretty clear: The super view of the cell is not the table view. You are discouraged from getting the index path of a cell with view hierarchy *math*. In Swift there are much better (and more efficient) ways for example a callback closure.

Comment: @vadian, can you help me with how to do it in a better way? Also, the equivalent of the same works perfectly for UICollectionView, I'm not understanding why this doesn't work here.

Comment: As I said, add a callback closure in the custom cell which is set in `cellForRow` and is called in an IBAction of the custom cell. The index path is captured. Protocol/delegate is not needed. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378515/issue-detecting-button-cellforrowat/46379494#46379494

Comment: @vadian, cellForRow can't be used as it is in my case. I have cells being deleted and because cellForRow isn't refreshed every time, some cells still have the last index saved which results in bugs. I have used it and then implemented this.

Comment: Alternatively pass the data model item to the cell in `cellForRow`. Then you are independent of index paths.

Comment: @vadian, I didn't get how to do that. Can you explain the same as an answer? Note that if row 2 gets deleted, row 3 doesn't effectively become 2 in cellForRowAt as it is not called instantly unless the tableView is reloaded.

Comment: `let tableView : UITableView = self.superview as! UITableView` Don't, simply don't. Don't force unwrap. Also, who said that the superView of a `UITableViewCell` is a `UITableView`? As you can see, it's not. Apple changed the hierarchy adding/removing views. Don't do that. Quick solution: Add a `IndexPath` property to the cell, and set it in `tableView(_:cellForRow:)`

Comment: Just add a property of the same type as the data source type in the custom cell and assign the item at index path in `cellForRow`. If you are going to mutate the data source item you might declare the type as `class` to get reference semantics.

Comment: @vadian, sorry but I still didn't get how this will return the correct indexPath. Can you please write an answer to the same. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, there is not enough information in the question to give a concrete suggestion. Once again: If the index path can change look for an object-based solution rather than an index(path)-based solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary issue is that you are making the inappropriate assumption that a cell's superview is the table view. Never make any assumption about the private subview structure of view classes provided by someone other than yourself.

The secondary issue is that you are putting too much logic inside the cell class. Your cell's delegate should simply pass itself (the cell) as the only parameter to the delegate method. Let the implementor of the delegate get whatever information it needs about the cell. If the delegate wants to know the cell's index path then the delegate can ask the table view. This logic does not belong in the cell.

A cell should never need to know its own index path nor what table view it is in. A cell should only care about its own views and nothing else.

Update your protocol method to take the cell as a parameter.

Update your cell's button handler to simply pass itself as the parameter to the delegate method.

Update the delegate method in the view controller to take the cell as the argument and get whatever it needs based on that cell.

Doing this makes the implementation of your cell class much simpler and it puts the logic where it belongs - in the view controller.

Comment: Thank you so much @rmaddy. You're like a sunshine in the darkness.