# How to pass data from a table view cell class back to view controller with the table view?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a view controller with a tableView and with custom cells.  I wanted to learn how to set it up so that when the buttons in the tableviewCells are clicked they can manipulate elements in the view controller that has the tableview.

Thanks to helpful contributors I have learned th answer is that there are 2 ways to have the button's clicked from a tableViewCell custom cell class interact with the viewController that has the tableView.  You can use delegates/protocols or you can use closures.  I provided a link to a youTube Video that explains the Delegate method as an answer to my own question below and another poster below provided a great succinct example of using closures.

Comment: you can add a delegate to the UITableViewCell subclass or a closure

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378515/issue-detecting-button-cellforrowat/46379494#46379494

Comment: Edit your question with proper formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a closure to call back button action from cell to view controller.

**CustomCell**

```
class CustomCell : UITableViewCell {

    var ClousureBtnActionHandler:((_ sender: AnyObject) -> Void)?


    @IBAction func btnInfoActionHandler(_ sender : AnyObject) {
        if self.ClousureBtnActionHandler != nil {
            self.ClousureBtnActionHandler!(sender)
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewController**

*TableView Datasource*

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell : CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as! CustomCell
        cell.ClousureBtnActionHandler = { sender in
            print("Do any thing with your button action")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the guidance here I was able to find this youTube tutorial which I found very helpful walking through how to set up delegates and protocols as a solution to having the cell class instruct the view controller what we would like it to do.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UPrBXUWPf6Q