# How to get the indexPath.row when I click a button on a table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image: This is my app]

Hello the image above is the UI of my todo list app, now I just want to show the detail of item (First Item, second Item etc) when I click the detail button in the tableviewcell. So in order to get the property of the item, I need to know the `indexPath` of the row that I just clicked on the detail button.

I have tried some properties of the tableview like `didSelectRowAt`, or `indexPathForSelectedRow`, but both not work. For `didSelectRowAt` user need to click on the row first then click the detail button, and that's not what I want, and the `indexPathForSelectedRow` is not working for me.

Comment: If you are using the AccessoryButton on the right you can call the tableView delegate method accessoryButtonTappedForRow and get its indexPath.

Comment: Show your current code for `cellForRowAt` and your button handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common, generalized solution for this type of problem is to connect the `@IBAction` of the button to a handler in the cell (not in the view controller), and then use a delegate-protocol pattern so the cell can tell the table when the button was tapped. The key is that when the cell does this, it will supply a reference to itself, which the view controller can then use to determine the appropriate indexPath (and thus the row).

For example:

- Give your `UITableViewCell` subclass a protocol:

  ```
  protocol CustomCellDelegate: class {
      func cell(_ cell: CustomCell, didTap button: UIButton)
  }
  ```
- Hook up the `@IBAction` to the cell (not the view controller) and have that call the delegate method:

  ```
  class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
      weak var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?

      @IBOutlet weak var customLabel: UILabel!

      func configure(text: String, delegate: CustomCellDelegate) {
          customLabel.text = text
          self.delegate = delegate
      }

      @IBAction func didTapButton(_ button: UIButton) {
          delegate?.cell(self, didTap: button)
      }
  }
  ```
- Obviously, when the cell is created, call the `configure` method, passing, amongst other things, a reference to itself as the delegate:

  ```
  extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { ... }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
          let text = ...
          cell.configure(text: text, delegate: self)
          return cell
      }
  }
  ```
- Finally, have the delegate method call `indexPath(for:)` to determine the index path for the cell in question:

  ```
  extension ViewController: CustomCellDelegate {
      func cell(_ cell: CustomCell, didTap button: UIButton) {
          guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }

          // use `indexPath.row` here
      }
  }
  ```

---

The other approach is to use closures, but again using the same general pattern of hooking the button `@IBAction` to the cell, but have it call a closure instead of the delegate method:

- Define custom cell with closure that will be called when the button is tapped:

  ```
  class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
      typealias ButtonHandler = (CustomCell) -> Void

      var buttonHandler: ButtonHandler?

      @IBOutlet weak var customLabel: UILabel!

      func configure(text: String, buttonHandler: @escaping ButtonHandler) {
          customLabel.text = text
          self.buttonHandler = buttonHandler
      }

      @IBAction func didTapButton(_ button: UIButton) {
          buttonHandler?(self)
      }
  }
  ```
- When the table view data source creates the cell, supply a handler closure:

  ```
  extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { ... }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
          let text = ...
          cell.configure(text: text, buttonHandler: { [weak self] cell in  // the `[weak self]` is only needed if this closure references `self` somewhere
              guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }

              // use `indexPath` here
          })
          return cell
      }
  }
  ```

I personally prefer the delegate-protocol pattern, as it tends to scale more nicely, but both approaches work.

---

Note, in both examples, I studiously avoided saving the `indexPath` in the cell, itself (or worse, “tag” values). By doing this, it protects you from getting misaligned if rows are later inserted and deleted from the table.

---

By the way, I used fairly generic method/closure names. In a real app, you might give them more meaningful names, e.g., `didTapInfoButton`, `didTapSaveButton`, etc.) that clarifies the functional intent.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the delegate method [tableView(_:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614996-tableview)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath)
```

However if you want to navigate to a different controller connect a segue to the accessory view button

If the button is a custom button see my answer in [Issue Detecting Button cellForRowAt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378515/issue-detecting-button-cellforrowat/46379494#46379494)

Comment: That is a button I insert to the cell, not an accessory Button :(

Comment: You should have mentioned that the button is not an accessory button. Use a callback closure. See the link in the updated answer.